# Crear evento en MySQL que permita actualizar un disparador con nuevos nombre de tabla refereciada

Tags: sql, trigger, events

tengo una consulta yo debo crear un evento o procedimiento en MYsql que actualice un TRIGGER el nombre de la tabla referenciada con los dos dígitos del año y una letra que pertenece al mes ya que el trigger queda sin funcionar cuando las tabla referenciada se modifica periódicamente al pasar el mes.

```
CREATE EVENT insertion_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2020-12-01 9:30:00'
DO  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insertar_mov AFTER INSERT ON mov20b
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
```

debo modificar el nombre del la tabla referenciada automáticamente cada mes...

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, sin mayúßcula sostenida (en el título) que eso no hace más visible la pregunta y sí se entiende como que estás gritando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Yo no entendi que necesitas o cual es el problema...